# Что лучше использовать: XHTML или HTML5?

Tags: xhtml, html5

Сабж. Есть ли смысл в "более чётком" XHTML, если выпущен современный HTML5?

**UPD:**
замечу, что мне **не** нужны конкретно возможности HTML5 специфические, типа локального хранилища и всяких audio-video.

Comment: А почему просто не использовать XHTML5? Все возможности HTML5 остаются, а "четкость" XHTML как XML сериализации добавляется.

Comment: Это еще что за зверюга?

Comment: это реверанс в сторону любителей «чёткости» :)
html5 допускает также использование синтаксиса xhtml.

Comment: @Syabrowka, то есть я могу на HTML5 запиливать `<br />` и `<img />`?
Превосходно)  
Хотя я сейчас подумал: собственно, а зачем это мне?

Comment: на html5 можно писать <br/> или <br> — оба варианта будут правильными. <img src="url" alt=""/> — правильный вариант для xhtml. С обязательным атрибутом alt даже тогда, когда по смыслу он не нужен. Этот же вариант для html5 тоже правильный. Но для html5 также правильным будет вариант <img src="url" />, <img src="url"> и даже <img src=url>

Comment: а ещё для html5 допустима конструкция например такая: <a href="ссылка на страницу статьи"><h2>Заголовок новости</h2><img src="картинка"><p>Краткий текст новости</a></a>. Значение тэга <a> и варианты его применения существенно переосмыслены в сторону здравого смысла.

Вообще, html5 — хорошая тема. Это язык, ориентирующийся на реальность.

Comment: @Syabrowka, про `alt` я знаю, просто не писал атрибутов.
Пожалуй, перейду на HTML5 и даже не буду писать `/>`

Да, я прочитал на w3.org про нововведения HTML5 - действительно классно.

Comment: @Syabrowka, оказывается, что `alt` в HTML5 всё-таки обязательный. 
По крайней мере валидатор выдаёт ошибку при его отсутствии.  
Но можно писать просто: `<img src="source" alt>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пока еще есть. Если верить тестам, еще ни один браузер полностью не соответствует спецификации HTML5, ну или, хотя бы, на 80-90%. Закупаем кукурузу, смотрим.

XHTML сейчас можно все еще рассматривать как основной язык разметки: его гибкости хватает для большинства сайтов, остальное "дожимается" яваскриптом. Но это ненадолго: уже в течение полутора лет, уверен, HTML5 станет на рельсы. Так что все зависит от задач: если это сайт на сейчас, либо ориентирован на страперскую аудиторию, используйте XHTML или даже HTML4. Иначе - можно потихоньку внедрять пятый, чем еще на одну стопятьсотую приближать его выход.

**UPD::** С учетом апдейта - юзайте HTML5 и не парьтесь: разницы не будет. <a href он и в африке ахреф. Без специальных фич он ничем особо не отличается, разве что куча тэгов урезаны =)

Comment: Сайт "на долго". Но дело в том, что если, как я узнал, IE HTML5 не понимает, то мне не подходит. Поддержка большого количества пользователей мне обязательно нужна.

Comment: не понимает != ничего не будет работать.   
Данная формульровка лишь указывает на то, что НОВЫЕ фичи, которые стали доступны только в HTML5 скорее всего не будут отображаться, либо будут отображаться некорректно в ИЕ. Для таких случаев давным давно добрые майкросовтовцы выпустили условные комментарии. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html  
Вещей, которые есть и в HTML5, и в XHTML, но при этом ИЕ их отображает только в XHTML я не припомню.

Comment: насчёт того, что IE не понимает — это радикальная чушь.
Устаревшие версии IE не знают по умолчанию новых тэгов, но это уже давно решено: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: С учетом апдейта см выше.

Comment: @knes, если HTML5 **без** новых тегов будет отображать без проблем - то отлично.

Comment: а какие могут быть проблемы? откуда им взяться?
Если вам специфические фичи не нужны, от новых тэгов можете воздержаться, то тогда вообще о чём речь? Тогда без всяких костылей хоть в IE5 будет работать всё точно так же, как и в html4. Только не будет дурацких необоснованных требований xhtml :)

Comment: @Syabrowka есть одна бага: при неуказанном доктайпе IE включает Quirksmode. В некоторых версиях IE5/6 оно включается и на <!DOCTYPE html>, так как не может определить что же за html используется. Это может реально доставать.
Так что проблемы-таки могут быть, печалька.

Comment: IE5? Господа знают толк в извращениях. IE6, кстати, тоже умер, хотя, в отличие от IE5, еще и не окончательно разложился. А IE7+ уже знают про «новый» DOCTYPE.

Хотя если платят стоящих того денег… Но в этих случаях вопрос не может стоять.

Answer (score 2):

Не забываем про кроссбраузерность... IE 6-8 не дружат с HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

пока существует Internet Explorer лучше XHTML, в плане кроссбраузерности.

Comment: последние два года пишу исключительно на html5. IE доволен, отображает всё корректно. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

а есть ли у xhtml преимущества, за исключением «большей чёткости»?

В старых браузерах были разные парсеры, обученные понимать html4, xhtml, xml, и чёрт-знает-что-ml в придачу. В современых браузерах есть один парсер, обученный понимать html5.

Если нравится чёткость, пишите на xhtml. Если после этого громоздкий незапоминаемый доктайп xhtml поменяете на `<!DOCTYPE html>`, то в общем случае получится корректный html5-документ.

Comment: Да ну, по-вашему, современные браузеры XHTML не поддерживают?

Comment: почему же?
корректный xhtml-документ является корректным документом html5. Отчего бы его не поддержать?